# Firebase - Error de Privacidad - Cuál es el motivo?

Tags: firebase, https

[image: El error Impide el acceso a la aplicación y pareciera un error de certificado de seguridad pero entiendo que firebase por defecto maneja sus propios certificados.]

Cómo pueod solucionar el problema que me muestra? parece ser un tema de certificado pero firebase se encarga de los certificados.

Comment: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de problemas te sugiero que llenes un reporte y esperes la respuesta, en el siguiente link podes elegir la seccion de SSL

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/hosting/

Sobre tu problema, lo que esta ocurriendo es que al no estar firmado tu dominio con un certificado seguro (SSL) no te esta dejando acceder al sitio de manera segura.

Lo que podes hacer para "solucionarlo" por el momento, es apretar en advanced ahi en el navegador cuando te salta ese error y clicar `Ingresar al sitio (no seguro)`  con esto podras debuguear y ver tu sitio mientras soporte resuelve tu problema.